# JSP problem deploying a java web application in tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, ant, tomcat6

I'm learning ANT and I'm trying to deploy a web application in tomcat 6.0.20 server.
I build the test application and I deploy it with the manager ant tasks and everything goes right. I load a HTML page and it works... When I try to view a JSP tomcat give me a JasperException, coused by a NullPointerException in the auto-generated Servlet. The JSP is almost an HTML file with jsp extension. The Exception is throwed in the _jspInit method when it tries to run the following:
_el_expressionfactory = _jspxFactory.getJspApplicationContext(getServletConfig().getServletContext()).getExpressionFactory();
somebody can help me? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have `jsp-api-*.jar` in `/WEB-INF/lib`. Remove it.

**EDIT**: Explanation

JSP API contains an abstract class `JspFactory`. It has a `static` field to store a server-specific `JspFactory` implementation. So, Tomcat sets a value of this field and JSP page initialization code reads it to obtain a `JspFactory` implementation. In your case you have two different `JspFactory` classes - one loaded by server classloader from server jars and another loaded by application classloader from `/WEB-INF/lib`. Because classes loaded by different classloaders are different classes, they have different `static` field values, therefore `JspFactory` obtained by the JSP code (`_jspxFactory`) is `null`.

This illustrates one of the possible problems caused by use of `static` fields.

Comment: Indeed and he's not the only one: [click here](http://www.google.com/search?q=NullPointerException+_jspInit). Get rid of all server-specific libraries in `/WEB-INF/lib`. They don't belong there and would only collide with real server-managed libraries in `Tomcat/lib`.

Comment: Thank you very mutch!
That was the problem!! I put that jar there to test something and I forgot to remove it.
Can you explain why it was an error? I know Tomcat has the jar in the lib dir, but why redundancy is bad?

Comment: @user279481: Explanation added.